# Checkout parameters not passing to google analytics dashboard

Tags: checkout, magento2.4.5, pwa, google-analytics, venia

We used below code in Magento PWA venia setup to pass the checkout values to Google analytics dashbaord. it is firing checkout event in google dashbaord. it is fine.

```
const proceedToCheckoutButton = !isCheckout ? (
        <div
     
        >
            <Button
                disabled={isPriceUpdating}
                priority={'high'}
                onClick={() => {
                    handleProceedToCheckout();
                    // below code for google analytics checkout
                    GTMEventTrigger({ route: window.location.pathname, event: 'proceed_checkout', title: document.title })
                   // above code for google analytics checkout
                   netcoreEvent('dispatch', 'Checkout', {
                        "total_items" : cartItems?.length,
                        "amount" : total?.value,
                        "Currency" : total.currency,
                        "items" : allCartItems
                    });
                }}
>
                
            </Button>
        </div>
    ) : null;
```

**Requirement** :

values like **total amount , added items in cart**  also need to pass to google analytics dashbaord. So i tried below code :

```
GTMEventTrigger({ route: window.location.pathname, 
                    
                    event('proceed_checkout', {
                        "total_items" : cartItems?.length,
                        "amount" : total?.value,
                        "Currency" : total.currency,
                        "items" : allCartItems
                    })
                 title: document.title })
```

**Issue** :

It is firing the event "checkout" in google analytics, but values like **total amount, items** are not passing to google analytics dashboard.
Am i passing values in wrong way ? is the code wrong ? How to debug ?

here is full code : src/components/CartPage/PriceSummary.js = > https://pastebin.com/PNSm2twf